A gap or possible mistake in a proof from Terrence Tao's blog post on the Chowla conjecture and the Sarnak conjecture
I was reading Terrence Tao's blog post the Chowla's conjecture and Sarnak's conjecture
There is one part that doesn't make sense to me. He wrote in the proof of Proposition 5 that
$$\mathbf{P}\left(\left|\frac{1}{m} \sum_{i=1}^m f_{\varepsilon}(n+i) \mu(n+i)\right| \right)<\left(C \exp \left(-\varepsilon^2 m / C\right)+o_{x \rightarrow \infty ; m, \varepsilon}(1)\right)\exp(o_{m\to \infty,\varepsilon,f}(m)) $$
and claimed that after simplifying the RHS we have
$$\mathbf{P}\left(\left|\frac{1}{m} \sum_{i=1}^m f_{\varepsilon}(n+i) \mu(n+i)\right| \right)<\varepsilon+o_{x\to \infty,\varepsilon,f}(1).$$
This doesn't make sense. The product $o_{x \rightarrow \infty ; m, \varepsilon}(1)\exp(o_{m\to \infty,\varepsilon,f}(m))$ can actually blow up. Does anyone know how to fix this or point out that I understood his point here?

I don't know what $x$ is, but you can first take $x \to \infty$ and then take $m \to \infty$.

@mathworker21 Sorry I had a typo. The second line of the equation should be $x\to\infty$ not $m\to\infty$. But your point makes sense. Yes, $m$ seems to be large but also can be fixed

Did you post this as a comment to the blog?

@martycohen I think mathworker21 basically addressed my confusion. $m$ here is a large fixed integer and $x$ can go to infinity. But let me read it more carefully.
